# Does Medusa's hair grow at the same pace as normal humans?

Tags: marvel, inhumans

In the Inhumans Tv series Medusa's hairs are shaved off by Maximus, but as she possesses powers related to controlling her hairs, does her hair grow at the pace of normal humans or it grows faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since they have not grown back by the end of the season/show - and she could have put them to good use in between, so if she could have made them grow faster, she most likely would have done so - it can be assumed that they grow at a normal (human) rate.

[image: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/marvelcinematicuniverse/images/4/40/...And_Finally_Black_Bolt_photo.jpg]